# Is there a way to get the status of the audio CD (idle/playing)?

Tags: command-line, data-cd

I am wondering if there is way to get the state of the CD drive in the command line if there is an audio cd inserted. Can you play a track on the CD and then get back somehow from the system the 'playing' status? Is there any record of the state of the audio cd in the system? (playing/stopped/idle/paused/etc)

Comment: What version of NIX are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, nobody tells the CD-Rom to **play** a CD but rather to read a CD and to send the read data to the audio interface of the computer.

When a CD is actually read, you cannot send/execute another SCSI command to the same drive, so there is no way to tell what you like.

What you can to is to call `cdrecord -minfo` to get the state of the currently inserted medium and to call `cdrecord -toc` to get the table of content.